# how to stop my alarm service after n number of days?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to start the alarm on specified day as the user input and i need to stop the alarm after some 'n' days. Here i am able to start alarm on specified day. But i am not able to stop it. So please anyone help me.

```
 private void Dailyalarm1(String time, String date )
{ 

    System.out.println(time);
    String min = time.substring(3, 5);
    System.out.println(min);
    int min1 = Integer.parseInt(min);

    String hour = time.substring(0, 2);
    System.out.println(hour);
    int hour1 = Integer.parseInt(hour);

    System.out.println(date);
    String day = date.substring(0, 2);
    System.out.println("date id: "+day);
    int day1 = Integer.parseInt(day); 

    EditText days = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.days);
    int  numOfDays = Integer.parseInt(days.getText().toString());

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent, 0);
    System.out.println("alarm service");

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min1);     
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day1); 
    System.out.println("start day is:"+ cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); 

    System.out.println("after alarm service starts date is "+ cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    System.out.println("number of days: "+numOfDays);


    System.out.println("Current date : " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"   
            + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    System.out.println("after caculating end date alarm service stop date is "+ cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

    Calendar calender  = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min1);     
    calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
    calender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 
    calender.add(Calendar.DATE, numOfDays); 

    do
    { 
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManagerStop = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManagerStop.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "alarm cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    while(cal.equals(calender));


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    System.out.println("after alarm service set repeat"); 

    Toast.makeText(this, "Start Daily Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AlarmManager.cancel(..)` cancels *matching* Intents. For the purpose of matching [`intent.filterEquals(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29) is used. Make sure that intents you used when crating alarm match the intent you use to cancel the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to set another alarm to preform a function when it goes off.